# Firebase: Failed to load function definition from source

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase functions and I keep receiving this error while trying to deploy or while using emulators.

> ⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[\p{Ll}\p{Lo}][\p{Ll}\p{Lo}\p{N}_-]{0,62}$/: Invalid property name in character class

the error occurs because of this statement, when i comment it the error does not occur.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
```

I tried to

1. reinstall firebase-tools
2. reinstall node and npm

I am using a 2012 macbook air, any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

this the only code in the project is in the `functions/index.js` file, otherwise it is a brand new firebase project initialized by `firebase init`

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')


// // wiered error, install older version of firebase-tools and check

// // function
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(async (req,res) => {
//     res.send('hello world') 
// })

// function test(){}
```

I tried the running `index.js` directly with `node.js` and got a more descriptive error message

> node index.js
> /Users/hammad/dev/firebase/prizeBonds/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-builder.js:96
> const validKeyPattern = /^[\p{Ll}\p{Lo}][\p{Ll}\p{Lo}\p{N}_-]{0,62}$/u;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[\p{Ll}\p{Lo}][\p{Ll}\p{Lo}\p{N}_-]{0,62}$/: Invalid property name in character class
> at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
> at Object. (/Users/hammad/dev/firebase/prizeBonds/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/index.js:71:14)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)

Node.js v18.15.0

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are able to reproduce this from a newly initialized project space so we can follow along and see the result for ourselves.  We can't reproduce this with one line of code.

Comment: @DougStevenson it is an empty firebase project with the only statement being the require statement in `functions/index.js`

Comment: Could you still edit the question to show the steps that anyone can take to reproduce this?  Start with running the Firebase CLI to init a new project.  It would be helpful if you pick up [here in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd#initialize-your-project).  Again, we need to see what all you have done, because one line isn't enough, and no one else has posted this sort of problem with that line.

Comment: "*I tried the running index.js directly with node.js*" - two things: 1) what exactly did you do there? Please edit the question to be clear how to reproduce this. 2) that's not a supported way of running functions. If you want to execute function code locally, you're supposed to use the emulator to create a container that can trigger function code.  But without any function defined, the emulator won't be helpful.

Comment: I'll also note that I still can't reproduce this with a new project, using any way I can think of to run the code at all. You have something extremely unusual going on.

Comment: Can you please edit your `package.json` into your question? (removing sensitive info as needed)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to low points, so leaving an answer for anyone who stumbles here like I did.

I had the same problem with 2015 macbook with the exact same error. After spending a day searching and trying out various different solutions, I finally found it to be a versioning issue due to different node versions installed on the same machine. Here are the steps I took:

1. Fixed the PATH to ensure that my downloaded node was being run. Earlier, it used to pick the node within the Anaconda package.
2. Fixed the npm config to update the prefix to use my local .npm-global directory to download firebase.
3. Downloaded latest versions of modules in package.json

After doing this, the functions finally got deployed.

Comment: can you recall which node and firebase versions you were using?

Comment: @hammi The Anaconda package has node v18.15.0 and firebase 12.4.0